# Using grammar with Web Speech API for a sentence (correct way)

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I want to create a simple Speech Recognition using **Web Speech API**. And for being more accurate I want to use `SpeechGrammarList()`constructor.

**Note:** there are lots of outdated answers saying grammar is not supported in chrome yet, but based on this reference it's now fully supported I think!:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechGrammarList/SpeechGrammarList#Browser_compatibility

I'm still not sure if it's supported in chrome now? and how to implement grammar correctly if it's working and supported in chrome?

I've tried to add the grammar but I don't know which one is the better implementation (Even if it's not supported yet someday it would, so I want to put it in my code)

We can add the grammar list based on words of the `paragraph` like this:

```
let paragraph = 'i was sent to earth to protect you to do'; 
let paragraphWords = paragraph.split(' ');

var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar paragraphWords; public <paragraphWords> = ' + paragraphWords.join(' | ') + ' ;';
var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
```

Or I should just insert the whole sentence:

```
let paragraph = 'i was sent to earth to protect you to do'; 
// let paragraphWords = paragraph.split(' ');

var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar paragraph ; public <paragraph> = ' + paragraph + ' ;';
var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old but I'll answer it for anyone else looking, as I've just done quite a bit of testing.

Grammars are definitely supported by Chrome now, I've tested this with some words and phrases it wasn't detecting, adding them to the grammar improves detection. Although it's not as good as the speech context phrases in the cloud speech API, you can't seem to change the spellings or add words completely out of the lexicon.

Looking at the phrase in the original post I wouldn't expect it to need to be added to the grammar, providing the language code is set correctly it should detect it OK. But if you did want to I would suggest either using `split(' | ')` or manually inserting `|` between words and phrases. See my example below.

When adding to the grammar to get it working I had to follow the examples in the docs by using the `|` operator otherwise it would not work, some things I tried broke it completely.

So in this fashion:

```
  var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar words; public <word> =  put | words | and phases | in here;'
  var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  var speechRecognitionList = new webkitSpeechGrammarList();
  speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
  recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechGrammarList/SpeechGrammarList#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Grammars still don't seem to be supported in Chrome, even on the official example on MDN. https://github.com/mdn/web-speech-api

You can still say words that are not colors, and it will detect them. It says it's 'compatible' on MDN but it's clearly not implemented yet.

A hacky approach that might work for future readers is setting recognition.maxAlternatives = 50 and looping through all the results. The word/phrase you are looking for might be there with a low confidence rating.

Comment: Yeah, from what I tested supplying custom Grammars didn't limit the transcription to only those words, it just improved the liklihood of detecting those words over other similar sounding words. Which proved useful in some contexts.

Comment: if it wasn't implemented trying to create a ```new webkitSpeechGrammarList()``` would throw an "is not a constructor" exception.

Comment: Has someone made a custom matcher to go through all the alternatives it gives and try to find best match to a JSGF grammar? It could even look at individual words in each alternative if they were short phrases and make a combined effort into matching the actual grammar.